# Virtual Allocation Unreasonably High

Tags: xen, migration, hard-drive, xenserver

Just upgraded our pool to Xenserver 6.2 and installed a brand new host, also with Xenserver 6.2.

Was excited about the new features since Xenserver was fully open-sources (over-allocate ram, ha live migration, etc). So decided to test things out and had a small windows xp dev-machine vm migrate live from one host to the brand new host.

The new host has 1TB of storage pool dedicated to it, and there are no other vm's running on it. The vm I migrated has a 20GB virtual disk.

The migration went smooth, but now my new host is reporting a virtual allocation of 661.4GB! And the only vm is the small 20gb one.

I've checked and the vm has no snapshots, and never has had any snapshots prior. So manually running the coalesce is not going to yield any results. I've had XenCenter rescan the SR to ensure it was not a reporting issue, and also rebooted this host to ensure the xen toolstack was not just reporting weird. No change.

I can likely export this vm, and re-import it to fix the problem, but this is not only very time consuming, but it won't work for production vm's that i still need to migrate over to the new host once this issue is solved (and hopefully does not repeat itself).

Please advise on possible solutions that have the least amount of down-time for the vm (if possible).

Comment: Why is this a problem for you? Virtual memory is effectively free.

Comment: virtual *disk* allocation. and unfortunately, no it's not free in xen... it will not allow you to overcommit disk space, so even if it's not being used, it won't let you do things like create new vm's, migrate other vm's, etc. xen/xenserver has some issues with virtual disk allocation common to snapshots going missing but still consuming space, etc. this is not my issue, but just an example of why it can be a problem.